# Remove everything between round brackets

Tags: php, regex

How to Remove everything between round brackets?

I have this paragraph with multiple brackets inside.

`Albert Einstein (/ˈælbərt ˈaɪnstaɪn/; {German} [ˈalbɐt ˈaɪnʃtaɪn] ( listen); 14 March 1879 – 18 April 1955) was a German-born theoretical physicist.`

i tried:

```
        $text = preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/",' ',$text);
        $text = preg_replace('/\[.*?\]/', ' ', $text);
```

and the output is this:

```
Albert Einstein ; 14 March 1879 18 April 1955) was a German born theoretical physicist.
```

i want to remove everything inside and output this.

```
 Albert Einstein was a German born theoretical physicist
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive regex in PHP:

```
(\((?:[^()]+|(?1))+\))\s*
```

The first capture group has: `\((?:[^()]+|(?1))+\)`

Inside the parens, you have `(?:[^()]+|(?1))+`, so that you have `[^()]+` as first option, or `(?1)` which refers to the first capture group, meaning you can have that same group inside the parens, which is the recursion part.

Then `\s*` outside just to remove extra spaces if any. Might be actually better if you put one at the front as well and replace with a single space, but the ideal would be to remove any double space after the first substitution I believe.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/dT7bQ0)

Comment: @mwweb I forgot to mention even though I did it in the demo link, you should also replace by nothing, or well, you can remove the `\s+` if you want and replace with a space, then proceed to remove all double spaces. All the same, I guess you could use `\s*` instead, if you have a period/comma after the closing paren.

Comment: Recursive expressions costs a lot and also yours will fail in this case http://regex101.com/r/xB6eF7

Comment: @revo It's only the last `\s+` which was causing this. I revised my regex to `\s*` a couple of hours ago, though the regex101 link was unchanged.

Comment: removing `\s+` will not fail. what means the `*` after the `s` in this case?

Comment: @mwweb `*` means 0 or more; which also means the match won't fail if there are no `\s`.